# Constructing the intersection of two abstract sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Appologies if this is a question that could be answered by reading a book on set theory. But this is something that's bugged me for a while (for the record I am trained in physics not maths). The problem is as follows, it seems that in order to construct a notion of "the intersection" of two sets, you need some way in which to identify two elements from two *different* sets as "the same". This is obvious if one has labelled the elements of the set, e.g.:

$$X:=\{1,2,3\},\quad Y:=\{3,4,5\},\quad X\cap Y=\{3\}. \tag{1}$$

It is clear in this case that as the elements of $X$ and $Y$ are natural numbers, we can appeal to the "exterior" set $\Bbb N$ to check which elements in $X$ are also contained in $Y$ and identify that $3\in X$ is "the same as" $3\in Y$.

However, it seems reasonable to me to define two sets whose elements are just "elements". The only information these sets carry is their cardinality and their elements are not labelled in any way. My question is, is there a meaningful way in which the intersection of two sets can be defined, given two entirely abstract sets of unlabelled, unordered "elements"?

If the definition of a set *requires* that the elements be more concrete than that then I suppose that unambiguously answers the question.

Comment: Yes; $X \cap Y = \{ z \mid z \in X \text {  and  } z \in Y \}$

Comment: I do not understand.  If all we are told is that $X$ is a set with three elements in it and $Y$ is also a set with three elements in it, then we do not have enough information to determine anything about $X\cap Y$ beyond that it too is going to be a set with some unknown integer number of elements possibly ranging from zero to three.

Comment: A set is a collection of elements and we have some way to unambiguously specify when an object belongs to a set or not.

Comment: @JMoravitz This is basically what I would have expected, so we do actually need to have labelled the elements of the set in some way.

Comment: That doesn't prevent us from talking about $X\cap Y$... it just prevents us from knowing much of anything specific about it beyond the obvious until knowing specifics about $X$ and $Y$ themselves.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Sure, but in order to say that $z$ is an element of *both* $X$ and $Y$ surely we need to appeal to something exterior, the example I gave in the question of appealing to the fact that $3\in \Bbb N$ seems "unnatural" to me in some sense as it presupposes the existence of a larger set containing the elements of $X$ and $Y$ from which we can cross-reference if they are "the same" or not.

Comment: A set can be either a List" of elements or specified by a property: the set of all and only the even numbers. Obviously the "listing" approach will work only for finite sets.